# Disappearing Unity Launch Bar Icons

Tags: 16.04, unity, icons

Beginning last week, possibly due to an update, individual app icons disappear from the Unity launch bar when I close them. They reappear after a reboot. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I can provide no more info.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: It would appear normal that app icons disappear when you close them, unless you pin them to the launcher.

Comment: They ARE pinned to he launch bar. That's what I'm talking about! They disappear when closed, but reappear after a reboot.

Comment: Perhaps try resetting compiz: rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*
then restart the system.